# Is $\{\{\ln(n)\} : n \in \mathbb{N)} \}$ dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Is the sequence defined by $a_n=\{\ln(n)\}$ dense in $[0,1]$?

Note: $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$

Comment: It converges to infinity,  so no.

Comment: No it does not remove your downvote.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $\{x\}$ denotes the *fractional part* of $x$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: false it denotes the fractional part

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou I just edited.

Comment: This could be better if non-standard or uncommon notations were defined in this question.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer I believe that notation *is* standard; that said, it probably should be defined in the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I have solved the problem I'm just posting it here to see what other solutions there might be

Comment: Do you know that if $\alpha$ is irrational then $\{n\alpha\}$ is dense in $0,1$? If so, then the above follows if you know that $\ln 2$ is irrational.

Comment: Then post your solution as part of the question, and ask for other solutions. @JoshuaBenabou

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, as you fastly guessed what it meant, I suppose this is standard but, IMO, it is not that common. I've studied mathematics for four years and never encountered this notation in any lecture or book. Thanks for your comment anyway

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: since ln(n+1)-ln(n) goes to zero. given a k, its eventually less than 1/k, so well have {ln(n)} intersecting each interval of the form [i/k,(i+1)/k) for n sufficiently large, so its dense in [0,1].

Comment: I think additionally, the problem is that individual numbers aren't dense in a set, a set of numbers is dense in a set, so the title $\{\ln n\}$ seems to refer to the *set* of values $\ln n$, rather than the set of values.

Comment: It's common and standard but it's not ... universal.   Without context in an analysis question it just isn't immediately apparent that that is what was meant.  No harm done though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given an irrational number, $\alpha$, we know the set of $\{n\alpha\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

If you know that $\ln 2$ is irrational, then $\{n\ln 2\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and since $n\ln 2 = \ln(2^n)$, this is a subsequence of your sequence, and hence your sequence is dense in $[0,1]$.

$\ln 2$ being irrational follows from $e$ being transcendental, since if $e^{p/q}=2$ then $e$ is a root of the rational polynomial $x^p-2^q$.

This is all a "big gun" approach to this question.

---

You actually don't need that $e$ is transcendental to use this technique - you can show that at least one of $\ln 2$ and $\ln 3$ is irrational, because otherwise $2^p=3^q$ for some integers $p,q$. Then either $\{n\ln 2\}$ or $\{n\ln 3\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

This works with any base -  $\{\log_b n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ - since at least one of $\log_b 2$ and $\log_b 3$ is irrational.

Comment: Very nice this is exactly the other kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\ln (n+1) - \ln n \to 0.$

Answer (score 2):

[Just to elaborate on zhw.'s hint.]

Suppose $(\{\ln n\})_n$ is not dense in $[0,1]$. Then there is some interval $(a,b)\subset [0,1]$ such that $\{\ln n\}\not\in(a,b)$ for every $n$. As $\ln n-\ln (n-1)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ we can choose $N$ big enough so that $$\ln n-\ln (n-1)<b-a\,\,\,\text{ if }\,\,\,n> N.\hspace{1cm}(\star)$$ 
Since $\ln n\to+\infty$, there is $M>N$ so that $\ln N-\ln M\geq1$, which [along with $(\star)$] tells us that $P=\{\{\ln n\}\}_{n=N}^M$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ with diameter/norm $d_P<b-a$, implying the contradiction $P\cap(a,b)\neq\phi.$