# Sequences $\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\}$ is is equidistributed modulo $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that the sequences $\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\}$ is equidistributed modulo $1$.

This question is for the following question:
 [Accumulation points form a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501748/prove-that-the-set-of-accumulation-points-is-circle-find-it-center-and-radius?noredirect=1).
It need to show that $\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\}$ is equidistributed modulo $2\pi$.
I think Weyl’s criterion will work!
Weyl's equidistributed criterion. The following are equivalent:
$$\{x_n\}\quad\text{is equidistributed modulo 1};$$

$$\forall~ \text{continuous & 1-peridic} f: \quad\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x_n)\rightarrow\int_0^1f ;$$

$$\forall~ k\in \mathbb Z^*:\quad \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2πikx_n}\rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: What is "equivalent modulo $1$"?

Comment: @Gary
Means $\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\}$mod $1$ is dense in $[0,1)$

Comment: I mean "equivalent" not "equidistributed". The one you wrote in the Weyl criterion.

Comment: @Gary Just a typo, adn fixed it!

Comment: [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) is asymptotic to $\log{n}$ and $\{\log{n}\}$ [is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063684/is-lnn-n-in-mathbbn-dense-in-0-1).

Comment: @rtybase Thank you very much!

Comment: @Riemann What?????????? No, equidistributed mod 1 does _not_ mean just "dense mod 1".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is right. Dense is weaker than equidistributed according to most definitions. See for example the Weyl equidistribution theorem to see the usual definition of ``equidistributed.''

Comment: @ShannonStarr According to "most" definitions? Can you give us a plausible reference where the two are the same?

Comment: Why the plural "sequences"? That's only one sequence.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am agreeing with you. I am merely seconding your point. A couple references for Weyl's equidistribution theorem are:Dym and McKean "Fourier Series and Integrals, Sec 1.6, pp.54-56; Stein and Shakarchi, "Fourier Analysis: An Introduction," Sec4.2, pp.105-113.The Wikipedia article on equidistribution also agrees with you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

Comment: One more comment is that density versus equi-distribution roughly follows the difference between Poincare's recurrence theorem versus Liouville's theorem on volume preserving measures. A good reference for that is V.I Arnol'd's book on "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics," for example.

Comment: @rtybase Yes, $s_n\sim\log(n)$ and $\{\log(n)\}$ is dense. **How** does that imply anything about $\{s_n\}$??? (I'm assuming you were using $\{\cdot\}$ for fractional part...)

Comment: @rtybase Thm: Knowing that $a_j\sim b_j$ and knowing everything about $\{a_j\}$ tells you nothing whatever about $\{b_j\}$.

Ok, that's a little colloquial. A precise statement that says the same thing: IOW If $(\alpha_j)$ and $(\beta_j)$ are *any* two sequences in $[0,1)$ then there exist $a_j$ and $b_j$ with $a_j\sim b_j$, $\{a_j\}=\alpha_j$ and $\{b_j\}=\beta_j$. Proof: $a_j=j+\alpha_j$, $b_j=j+\beta_j$.

Comment: @rtybase (Cor $s_n\sim\log n$ does not imply that $\{s_n\}$ is dense.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I guess I should have not used the "asymptotic" word. Harmonic series and $\log{n}$ [are more than asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508574/how-to-prove-that-as-n-s-nb-infinitely-often) is another link.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at this general fact:

> If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n\ge0$ with $a_n\to0$ and
> $\sum a_n\to\infty$ then $\{\sum a_n\}$ is equidistributed modulo 1.

**Proof:**

Let $a,b\in [0,1]$ assume $a< b$ then there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0\le a_n< b-a$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

Now let us define partial sum $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ then $s_n\to \infty$ (increasing sequence).

Choose $M$ such that it is the least positive integer greater or equal to $s_{n_0}$, i.e. $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(M-1)<s_{n_0}\le M$.

We know there exist $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_k > (M+a)$.Hence the set $\{k\in\mathbb{N}|s_k > (M+a)\}$ is non empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Choose $n_1=min\{k\in\mathbb{N}|s_k > (M+a)\}$, (existance by well ordering principle).

Now observe that $(M+a)<s_{n_1}<(M+b)$ and hence $a<\{s_{n_1}\}<b$ .
(here ${s_{n_1}}$ denotes fractional part of $s_{n_1}$ ).

So the fractional part of $s_n$ is dense in $[0,1]$

---

Apply this to solve the above problem.

Comment: Nice fact! Thank you!

Comment: This is not equidistribution

Comment: Dear @Bananach, the definition is given here for 'equidistribution modulo 1'-https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1

Comment: Dear @Bananach I agree that it is not equidistribution, but it is **equiditribution modulo 1** which is defined differently .  Please read the discussion in comments. And if a down vote makes you happy then it is fine. :)

Comment: NO, saying it's dense does not say it's equidistributed mod 1. That comment is **wrong**. Can you give us the actual definition? In fact not only is the proof incomplete, the general result you state is false.

Comment: @Riemann nice or not, it's a **false** fact; the opinion expressed in another comment notwithstanding, "equidistributed mod 1" is _not_ the same as "dense mod 1".

Comment: @Noobmathematician Yes, the definition is given at that link! I don't see how you get the idea from that wikipedia article that equidistribution mod 1 is the same as density mod 1. Its says clearly that $(x_n)$ is equidistributed mod 1 if $(frac(x_n))$ is _equidistributed_ on $[0,1)$; otoh the sequence is dense mod 1 if the fractional parts are _dense_ in $[0,1)$.

Comment: @Noobmathematician Let  $L=[0,1/2)$, $R=[1/2,1)$. Say $(x_n)\subset[0,1)$ is a sequence dense in $[0,1)$ consisting of one element of $L$ followed by two elements of $R$, then one element of $L$ and two elements of $R$ etc.Then $(x_n)$ is dense in$[0,1)$ but not equidistributed, since (speaking loosely) only a third of terms lie in $L$. Since $frac(x_n)=x_n$ this says that the sequence is dense mod 1 but not equidistributed mod 1.

Comment: (that wasn't intended as a counterexample to the result you state, just a counterexample to the notion that dense mod 1 implies equidistributed mod 1.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I assumed the fact equidistribution mod 1 means density mod 1and said 'it is done!'. Apologies if that is wrong .

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why is this general fact false? Is the proof wrong?

Comment: yes, the proof is wrong, simply because you state equidistribution and prove just density

Comment: Exercise: construct a counterexample to the claim. (The same sort of thing as in the example I gave, but a little more complicated...)